# error: type 'gr::fec::generic_decoder::sptr' {aka 'class boost::shared_ptr<gr::fec::generic_decoder>'} argument given to 'delete', expected pointer

Tags: c++

I have the code below and I am trying to deallocate some memory which is causing a memory leak error, and I am struggling to figure out how to delete it.

Below is a snippet of code

```
Framework_Decoder::Framework_Decoder()
{
    code initializing variables...

      sptrExternFwDecoder = fec::code::cc_decoder::make(
      PHY_DECODE_MAX_FRAMESIZE_LENGTH,
      Constraint_K,
      OneOver_Rate,
      GeneratorPolys,
      LFSR_StartState,
      LFSR_EndState,
      Mode,
      PaddedToNearestByte);
}

void
Framework_Decoder::ConvolutionalDecode_SpiralViterbi(
   uint32_t nInputCodedDataBits,
   framework_uchar_internal* pInputCodedDataBits,
   uint32_t nOutputDecodedDataBits,
   framework_uchar_internal* pOutputDecodedDataBits)
{
   bool bFrameSmallerThanMax =
      sptrExternFwDecoder->set_frame_size((int)nOutputDecodedDataBits);

   if (!bFrameSmallerThanMax)
   {
      TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_VERBOSE, "WARNING in " << TRACE_COUT_METHOD_NAME << ":  Output frame size requested is larger than");
      TRACE_LEVEL_GTEQ(TRACE_VERBOSE, "        PHY_DECODE_MAX_FRAMESIZE_LENGTH. Truncated but continuing.");
   }

   sptrExternFwDecoder->generic_work(
      pInputCodedDataBits, pOutputDecodedDataBits);
   return;
}

// mwk 12/31/2019
// Added to fix the memory allocation leak, hopefully....
Framework_Decoder::~Framework_Decoder()
{
    // delete any allocated memory
    if (sptrExternFwDecoder)
       delete (*sptrExternFwDecoder);
    return;
}
```

I believe the sptrExternFwDecoder variable is causing problems and not being deallocated correctly...and it is being called over and over again.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code can result in either compilation error or a memory leak but not both at the same time. If there's a compilation error, you probably need to remove a `*` from the `delete` line. Better yet, stop whatever you are doing and read about memory management with smary pointers like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: It is a `shared_ptr` which does not (and cannot) be `delete`d. The destructor will clean up for you. If there is a leak, it is in code you didn't share. Trying to delete the `shared_ptr` will just make the problem worse.

Comment: So when I remove the delete function, the code compiles correctly, but i see the memory steadily increase.  Ultimately, I would like to clear the allocated memory in the Framework_Decoder class or the sptrExternFwDecoder variable.  So, you say the destructor Framework_Decoder::~Framework_Decoder() should clean up the allocated memory?